# Updating OpenSSL in macOs X Capitan for python 3.5

Tags: python, macos, openssl

I am trying to update OpenSSL for Python 3.5 running on a MacOS El Capitan. I have installed the new version through this command:

```
brew install openssl
```

I got the following on the shell:

```
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2g: 1,678 files, 12.0M
```

Then, I check the versions on the shell:

```
$ python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"  
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016  
$ openssl version  
OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
```

It seems there are two versions of OpenSSL, and Python continues with the oldest version. I need to get the updated version of OpenSSL for running the Python programs, but I do not know how to make Python use the newest version. Neither do I know how to use the information provided after installing the new version with brew.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this problem!
The point is that Python 3.5 works with OpenSSL 0.9.8. The solution is installing Python 3.6.5 with a particular configuration to include 'OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017'.

```
brew install openssl
brew link openssl --force  # if you need too
brew install python3  --with-brewed-openssl  # this brings Python 3.6.5, and not 3.5
```

Comment: did you have to uninstall your existing **python 3.4** before you could do the `brea install python3 --with-brewed-openssl` to bring in **python 3.6.5**?

Comment: No. It was not necessary. Both version can coexist. As I work with PyCharm, I had to select the Python version when I started a new project. That was enough.